# Changing role prefix in Spring Security 6

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am new to java and spring security. In spring security 6, lot of classes and interfaces have been deprecated.

I understand in Spring Security 6 we need to use AuthorizationManager however I am not sure how to set the role prefix in Spring Security 6.

The RoleVoter had method to set role prefix however it is also deprecated in Spring Security 6.

Below is my code which needs to migrated to Spring Security 6.

```
import java.util.List;
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDecisionManager;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDecisionVoter;
import org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor;
import org.springframework.security.access.vote.AbstractAccessDecisionManager;
import org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Component
public class AccessDecisionManagerCustomizer {

    @Autowired
    protected MethodInterceptor methodSecurityInterceptor;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        if (methodSecurityInterceptor instanceof MethodSecurityInterceptor) {

            AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager = ((MethodSecurityInterceptor) methodSecurityInterceptor).getAccessDecisionManager();
            if (accessDecisionManager instanceof AbstractAccessDecisionManager) {

                List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> voters = ((AbstractAccessDecisionManager) accessDecisionManager).getDecisionVoters();
                RoleVoter scopeVoter = new RoleVoter();
                scopeVoter.setRolePrefix("SCOPE_");
                voters.add(scopeVoter);

            } else
                // throw exception here
        } else
            // throw exception here
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

I did check the documentation but could not find anything related to changing role prefix in Spring Security 6.

Below SecuritFilterChain class is in our custom oauth library.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter;

import com.oauth.web.filter.SSOCookieAuthenticationFilter;
import com.oauth.web.security.oauth2.PreAuthAccessDeniedHandler;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.oauth.web")
public class SecurityFilterChain {

    @Autowired
    SSOCookieAuthenticationFilter sSOCookieAuthenticationFilter;

    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterAfter(sSOCookieAuthenticationFilter, ExceptionTranslationFilter.class);
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new PreAuthAccessDeniedHandler());
    }
}
```

Below is our config class from one of our project which is extending the above SecurityFilterChain class

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityCustomizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.HeadersConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfTokenRepository;
import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

import com.oauth.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SSOSecurityConfig extends SecurityFilterChain {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions(createFrameOptionCustomizer())
                .contentSecurityPolicy(csp -> csp.policyDirectives(CSP)))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to(InfoEndpoint.class), EndpointRequest.to(HealthEndpoint.class)).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/login**", "/callback/", "/oauth2/authorization/**", "/error**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated())
                .httpBasic(withDefaults());
        
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.csrfTokenRepository(createCsrfTokenRepository()));
        super.configure(http);
        return http.build();
    }
    
    private CsrfTokenRepository createCsrfTokenRepository() {
        CookieCsrfTokenRepository cookieCsrfTokenRepository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
        cookieCsrfTokenRepository.setCookiePath("/");
        return cookieCsrfTokenRepository;
    }

    private Customizer<HeadersConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.FrameOptionsConfig> createFrameOptionCustomizer() {
        if (Arrays.stream(environment.getActiveProfiles()).anyMatch("local"::equalsIgnoreCase)) {
            return HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable;
        }
        return HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::sameOrigin;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also add and example how you are using this `AccessDecisionManagerCustomizer` component ?

Comment: Hi  @AndreiLisa ,

We have our own custom oauth library in which this AccessDecisionManagerCustomizer component is present.

In our other project we have added this custom oauth library as dependency. In that project we have one config class which is extending class of this custom oauth library. I have updated the code above.

Comment: how to change the prefix is documented here in the spring security docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/architecture.html#authz-authorities

Comment: @Toerktumlare Please correct me if I am wrong but I guess it will add prefix to all the GrantedAuthorities. What I want to achieve is instead of List<AccessDecisionVoter>, I need to get its equivalent i.e. AuthorizationManager and add another RoleVoter with custom prefix.